# Limit of a Certain Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that the sequence
$$
s_n=\prod_{k=1}^n \left( 1-\frac{1}{2^k} \right)
$$
converges and has nonzero limit.

It was trivial to show that the sequence converges (it is bounded and monotone so it must by the Monotone Convergence Theorem). However, it seems less trivial to show that the limit is nonzero. I have tried bounding it below by a converging series, taking the $\log$ of the product and considering that series, treating it like a Basel Identity problem, and using a Taylor Series argument, all to no avail. I'm really just looking for a hint how to actually show that the limit can be nonzero. How should I think about this?

Comment: **Hint.** Analyse the sequence $\log(s_n)$ and use $1-\frac{1}{x} \leq \log(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\ln(s_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right).$$

We can remark that for all $k$, $$\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right)<0.$$
Moreover, if $n\to\infty$,

$$\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right)\sim -\frac{1}{2^k}.$$

I let you conclude.

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{2^k}$ converges absolutely, hence the product converges, which means that it's partial products converges to a nonzero number.